# Background Fetch iOS UIBackgroundFetchResult unrecognize selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-fetch

I am following [AppCoda:Working with Background Fetch Programming](http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-background-fetch-programming/) and getting some error. I already created base app that can display table with data from its source, also it `UIRefreshControl` works well.

Then I started to create its background fetching process. I already enable its background capability, set minimum interval time on appDelegate, and implement `application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:` method.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    MyTableViewController *viewController = (MyTableViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    [viewController fetchNewDataWithCompletionHandler:^(UIBackgroundFetchResult result) {
        completionHandler(result);
    }];
}
```

I build this project, and still work well. Then I want to test its background process by duplicating existing project scheme and enable option *launch due to a background fetch event*. I pressed run, and it give me error due to unrecognize selector.

```
[UINavigationController fetchNewDataWithCompletionHandler:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb99280b800
```

This is my `fetchNewDataWithCompletionHandler`:

```
- (void)fetchNewDataWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    XMLParser *xmlParser = [[XMLParser alloc] initWithXMLURLString:NewsFeed];
    [xmlParser startParsingWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *dataArray, NSError *error) {
        if (success) {
            NSDictionary *latestDict = [dataArray objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *latestTitle = [latestDict objectForKey:@"title"];

            NSDictionary *existingDict = [self.arrNewsData objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *existingTilte = [existingDict objectForKey:@"title"];

            if ([latestTitle isEqualToString:existingTilte]) {
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
                NSLog(@"No new data found");
            }
            else {
                [self performNewFetchedDataActionsWithDataArray:dataArray];
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
                NSLog(@"New data was fetched");
            }
        }
        else {
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed);
            NSLog(@"Failed to fetch");
        }
    }];
}
```

I don't know what is going on here, what happened with my `fetchNewDataWithCompletionHandler`?. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Error shows that your rootViewcontroller is UINavigationController. your method exist in "MyTableViewController" class, so make sure you create that class object.

Comment: already create fetchNewDataWithCompletionHandler in my MyTableViewController class. What's wrong?

Comment: you are using wrong class. you supposed to use "MyTableViewController" instead of "UINavigationController".

Comment: Look at my performFetchWithCompletionHandler:, I use MyTableController to create viewController object. Am I wrong, @nadim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your viewController as rootViewController

```
MyTableViewController *viewController = [[MyTableViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
```

Then configure your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: to support dequeue cell identifier

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
```

Let me know if that's work.

Comment: Glad to help you, @yankoo